# How do news iOS apps like Bloomberg, ABCNews, CBSNews, etc. work?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, rss

Do they use UIWebview, RSS, NSURLRequest exclusively?

Comment: Each application is going to be a different case, and unless one of the developers of those applications is willing to comment on this, we can only speculate as to their composition.

Comment: You are welcome to speculate... I am just hoping to learn the technologies that probably are being used in this type of apps.

Comment: I disagreed with the decision to close this question.  The question is real.  It should have been given chanced for some one who have knowledge in this subject to answer if so chosen.  In the question I did give 3 programming related technologies that I think it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sure they use a host of features. i would *guess* that they only use UIWebViews when they're displaying a full article. i'd recommend looking into:

- https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking for handling URL requests etc(by the guys who make gowalla)
- https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser for handling RSS feeds